# not set property when update the model in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `BaseSchame` in this `Schma` if Model is created it must set Value for two properties:

```
schema.pre("save", function (next) {
  if (!schema.isNew) {
    this.createDate = new Date();
    this.createBy = "kianoush";
}
  next();
});
```

if update must be set value for two property :

```
  schema.pre("updateOne", function (next) {
    this.updateDate = new Date();
    this.updateBy = "kianoush";
    next();
  });
```

but when I update the model it not save the `updateDate` and `updateBy` ..

```
 UpdateRole(role) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Role.updateOne({ _id: role._id }, { $set: { ...role } }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(res);
      });
    });
  }
```

and this is `Controller:`

```
await RoleReposiotry.UpdateRole(req.body)
      .then(() => {
        this.Ok(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.BadRerquest(res, err);
      });
```

What's the problem? how can I solve this problem?

**Update :**

```
  module.exports = function BaseSchema(schema, options) {
  schema.add({
    isDelete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    owner: { type: String },
    updateDate: { type: String },
    updateBy: { type: String },
    deleteDate: { type: String },
    deleteby: { type: String },
    createDate: { type: String },
    createBy: { type: String },
  });

  schema.pre("save", function (next) {
    if (!schema.isNew) {
      this.createDate = new Date();
      this.createBy = "kianoush";
    }
    next();
  });

  schema.pre("updateOne", function (next) {
    this.updateDate = new Date();
    this.updateBy = "kianoush";
    next();
  });
};
```

and this is the Role Schame :

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BaseSchema = require("./BaseSchema");

const RoleSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
});


RoleSchema.plugin(BaseSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Role", RoleSchema);
```

Comment: Post the schema definition

Comment: @AdamAzad I update the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the docs mentions that "updateOne" middleware don't have access to document but the query model instead: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes

Example of your use case copied from the link above:

```
schema.pre('updateOne', function() {
  this.set({ updatedAt: new Date() });
});
```